# How to create dropdown menu from model in django

Tags: python, django, variables, global

I'm currently trying to create a drop-down menu for my Post categories in my base.html so that it gets displayed on every one of my templates.
Later on, I want a user to simply click on a category item and get forwarded to the specific category.

I'm a bit confused as to what I should include in my forms and how to call that form in my base.html.

**base.html**

```
...
<body>
        <div class="page-header">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="top-menu"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</button></a>
            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="top-menu"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Account</button></a>
            <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            {% endif %}


            {% if user.is_anonymous %}
            <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="top-menu"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Sign-Up</button></a>
            <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="top-menu"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button></a>
            {% endif %}

        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            <label for="{{ category_form.category.id_for_label }}">Select a category:</label>
            {{ category_form.category }}
        </div>
```

**views.py:**

```
from .forms import PostForm


def category_dropdown(request):
    return render (request, 'quickblog/base.html')
```

**models.py**

```
...
# Categorys of Post Model
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    categorycover = fields.ImageField(upload_to='categorycovers/', blank=True, null=True, dependencies=[
        FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
            format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 600, 'max_height': 600}))
    ])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

#Post Model
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
...
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'category', 'tag', 'postcover', 'postattachment',]
    captcha = CaptchaField()
```

**settings.py**

```
...
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.core.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'quickblog.quickblog.context_processors.category_form',
)
...
```

**context_processor.py**

```
from .forms import PostForm

def category_form(request):
    form = PostForm()
    return {'category_form': form}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will automatically make it a drop-down menu with your current form code. You just need to make that form available using a **context processor**.

In your settings file, under templates, context_processors add something like `your_project.your_app.context_processors.category_form'

And in your app (quickblog I believe) add a file:

**context_processors.py**

```
from .forms import PostForm

def category_form(request):
    form = PostForm()
    return {'category_form': form}
```

---

By the way, to reproduce your current code I had to make a few changes.

In views.py
I changed `categories = Category.objects.title()` to `categories = Category.objects.only('title')`

and then got rid of that and just used the form instead

```
from .forms import PostForm
def category_dropdown(request):
    form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'quickblog/base.html', {'form': form})
```

And then finally to

```
def category_dropdown(request):
    return render (request, 'quickblog/base.html')
```

since the context_processor is now doing the work.

---

I believe in your comment you are asking how do you render just the drop-down.

In your template you'd do something like this:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    <label for="{{ category_form.category.id_for_label }}">Select a category:</label>
    {{ category_form.category }}
</div>
```

Please see [Django's docs on the subject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) for more details.

---

### Files I used to get it working

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Categorys of Post Model
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

#Post Model
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'category']
```

**settings.py**

```
...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django_settings_export.settings_export',
                'quickblog.context_processors.category_form'
            ],
        },
    },
]
...
```

Comment: Hey, thx for your update, but how to display???

<div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a>{{ category_form }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: I updated my response. Please select it as the answer if it helps. If not, please clarify what you are asking in your follow up question.

Comment: I justed updated my question with some additional stuff... The only thing i see right now is that basr.html displays the lable: "Select a category:" but no dropdown after that... Did i missed something?

Comment: It is working for me, I'll have to double check your code. Do you have some content in the DB?

Comment: Everything I've checked is working. Can you try it without the captcha? Also, I'm trying it without the tag and category cover fields because I don't have those models.

Comment: What version of Django are you using? I triple checked everything and it should work but it doesn't

Comment: 2.0.5. I uploaded everything to github for you to check out: https://github.com/tutordelphia/django_sandbox . If you want to do the same, I'll look at your project for issues.

Comment: Heyho, yes plese. Have a look at: https://github.com/rsmvdl/quickblog
You have to fully initialize the app.

Comment: Please see my latest edit. I had assumed that you used the constant TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS but apparently, that isn't getting called. If you add it to TEMPLATE under OPTIONS, context_processors it works.

Comment: Dude! You are awsome :D
Now it works.
One last thing, if i want to call a specific view, e.g. a filter to show only posts from specific categories who do i call them? Then i have a complete picture.

Comment: I'm glad that finally works! I'd be happy to look at that other question with you in a different thread once you've done some research and have tried some things. Also, note that Stackoverflow considers a question unanswered if it doesn't have at least one answer with an upvote (even if it is checked).

Comment: How can I make it automatic, without create button?

Answer (score 0):

You can us some thing like this :

**Forms.py** :

```
    class MyModel2(forms.Form):
         color = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select)
```

**Index.html**:

```
<form method="POST" action = "ACTION_OR_VIEW_URL_ON_SUBMIT_HERE">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="colorSelect">Choose color</label>
    <select type="text" id="colorSelect" name="colorSelect">
        <option selected>GREEN</option>
        <option>BLUE</option>
        <option>RED</option>
        <option>ORANGE</option>
        <option>BLACK</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes but the Problem is that i get my Vaules from Database thats why this solution does not fit 4 me